# LBW and aiding umpire

Tags: cricket

We get replays, Hawk-Eye wherein we get to know that the ball was pitch in line or outside leg/off stump.

Is having lines drawn in the middle of the pitch from stump to stump a bad idea?

I think the umpire will get to know the pitching of the ball very precise with those lines.

Comment: It will also help bowlers to ball precisely!!

Comment: @JAVY: Yeah, true. But I feel, that isn't harming the game by any means. Again, its a personal opinion.

Comment: No , it can distract both batsman and bowler, and this line will help the bowlers.

Comment: While this is an interesting idea, I don't think it's a good fit for Stack Exchange's Q&A format - any answers are going to be based on people's opinions rather than verifiable facts.

Comment: @WedaPashi , [Here](https://www.quora.com/Cricket-sport-Why-dont-they-make-a-line-on-the-cricket-pitch-indicating-the-line-of-the-stumps#!n=12) is a similar Quora question.

Comment: I don't think that this should be done as it would also allow the bowlers to bowl in a perfect line

Comment: It will also help batsmen in at least two ways. 1. They know if a ball is pitched outside leg stump, and hence, can be safely paddled away. 2. They can make a better judgement on which balls to leave, reducing chances of slip catches, LBWs, and even bowled in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an umpire, it would be a distraction not a help.  We stand with our eyes  generally over middle stump, although this can change if leg stump is particularly important say for a left arm over bowler to a right hander.

The extra lines would act as a distraction and would not help with the decision making process.